# Comparing two attributes values using SAX and Java

Tags: java, parsing, sax

This is my security.xml

I want to test `temperature` and `t` have the same **label** and `presence`  and `p` have the same **label** using SAX and java.

could someone help me  !!?

```
 <root>

   <component classname="temp.impl.Temperatureservice" name="TemperatureSecurity">
<attributes>
       <attribute>

     <name> temperature</name>

        <label>L</label>

     </attribute>
 </attributes>
     </component> 


  <component classname="pres.impl.Presenceservice" name="PresenceSecurity">
<attributes>
    <attribute> 

<name>presence</name>

      <label>H</label>

   </attribute>
   </attributes>
 </component>

 <component classname="anal.AnalyserService" name="ManagerSecurity">
 <attributes>
       <attribute >

      <name>t</name>

        <label>L</label>

      </attribute>

<attribute>

 <name>p</name>

     <label>H</label>

        </attribute>
</attributes>
   </component>  


</root>
```

what i tried :

```
  public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<Component> compList = null;
private Component comp = null;
boolean bnameatt = true;
boolean bName = true;
boolean blabel = false;
String label;
private String temp;
private String lab;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("component")) {

        String name = attributes.getValue("name");

        comp = new Component();
        comp.setName(name);
        //initialize list
        if (compList == null) {
            compList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        temp = attributes.getValue("name");
        bnameatt = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("label")) {
        lab = attributes.getValue("label");
        blabel = true;

    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("temp " + temp + " lab " + lab);
    if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")) {

        label = lab;
    } else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
        System.out.println("temp " + temp + " lab " + lab);
        if (lab.equals(label)) {
            System.out.println("okk");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not ok");
        }
    }
    blabel=false;
    bnameatt=false;
}
```

}

i have a NullPointerException at saax.MyHandler.endElement(MyHandler.java:56) `if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")`

Comment: How did you try to go on solving this? What's your problem? what are you stuck with?

Comment: i add what i tryed to the post

Comment: your example is incomplete so it's hard to tell what's wrong. do you have an endElement defined? somewhere your builder and your boolean flags need to get reset. also characters is the wrong place to do the comparison. you need to post an MVCE and be more clear about what your error is.

Comment: i general how to compaire the value of to components !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("component")) {
                String classname = attributes.getValue("classname");
                String name = attributes.getValue("name");
                System.out.println("path du componsant= " + classname + "  nom de composant est " + name);
                bName = true;
            }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("attribute")) {
                temp = attributes.getValue("name");

                lab=attributes.getValue("label");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

            if (temp != null) {
                if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")) {

                    label = lab;
                } else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
                    System.out.println("temp " + temp + " lab " + lab);
                    if (lab.equals(label)) {
                        System.out.println("okk");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("not ok");
                    }
                }
                blabel = false;
                bnameatt = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the endElement callback to save what to you built using builder and builder1, and then to compare it to the previous results. Something like:

```
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
       if (builder.toString().equals("temperature")) 
           temprature_label = builder1.toString();
       else if (builder.toString().equals("t")) {
            if (builder1.toString().equals(temprature_label)) 
                System.out.println("okkk");
            else
                System.out.println("not ok");
       }
    }
```